# 新規プロジェクトでエラー: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath'

Tags: android-studio

プログラマ歴はそれなりですが、Androidプログラミング超初心者です。

Windows7にAndroidStudio(3)をインストールして新しいプロジェクトを作成したのですが
いきなりエラーでビルドが通りません。

エラーは何件かありますが、基本的に以下のようなものです。

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not 
resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details
```

設定はすべて初期状態でプロジェクトも空っぽです。
そもそもがこういうものなのでしょうか？

その後、Dependenciesを修正したらビルドが通りました。

app/build.gradleの内容

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        ～中略～
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        ～中略～
    }
        ～中略～
}

dependencies {
        ～中略～
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'  //←appcompat-v7:26.1.0
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.+'  //←runner:1.0.1
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.+'  //←espresso-core:3.0.1
}
```

ちなみに
~\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\
以下にはそれぞれ
該当のバージョンのライブラリは存在せず、古いバージョンがありました。

またjunit:junit:4.12については
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\junit-4.12.jar
があるのですが、ここを参照する方法がわかりません。

これらは（Studioが自動でセットアップしてくれるのではなく）自力で調達して参照設定なければならないのでしょうか？

Comment: gradleが参照するrepositoryに該当のバージョンのライブラリが含まれていないのではないでしょうか。projectの方のbuild.gradleはどうなっていますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。projectのbuild.gradleは、repositories{google() jcenter() }となっていますが、ここのことでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven
より

全てのプロジェクトでgoogle()のリポジトリを読み込めるようにする
`<projectRoot>/build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

あるいはモジュールの方に追加するでも良いかもしれません。

`<projectRoot>/app/build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

Comment: allprojects.repositories.google()は最初から記述がありました。repositories.maven.urlを追記しましたが（当然かもしれませんが）上位バージョンのライブラリは解決できませんでした。